# Why is mathematica producing the incorrect derivative for a very simple problem?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, wolfram-language

I've been attempting to check my work with Mathematica, and it's giving me the incorrect answer for a reasonably simple derivative. It also gave me the wrong solution for a different problem. I've included a screenshot of the work by hand and a screenshot of the incorrect answer.

What could be causing this error?

[The Image shows a picture of the incorrect answer for a derivative](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A46x8.jpg)

[This is the solution worked out by hand.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T1W7q.jpg)

Comment: It appears to me that both answers are correct, which you should be able to check with some algebra.  Try `Simplify` and you may be able to get Mathematica to express its answer in a more similar form to yours.

Comment: Yeah, it's the same, which you can check by turning your x^2 to (2x^2 - x^2), and then factoring out 2x (from 2x^2 + 4x). The path you took is using the definition (limit based), but you can get the same answer as Mathematica in a more straightforward way by using the quotient rule and the table of derivatives.

Comment: It's interesting.  WolframAlpha produces an answer very similar to yours but I always thought that Mathematica and WolframAlpha used the same engine underneath.  Here is the WolframAlpha version: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=derivative+of+x%5E2%2F%28x%2B2%29

Comment: Thank you. This helped me solve my problem. Interesting that WolframAlpha produces a similar answer to mine but Mathematica does not.